# add curl parmeter CURLOPT_USERPWD IOS

Tags: ios, curl

This is  PHP code:you need a POST call with parameters  methode = getAll:

$filters = array(); 
        $filters['denomination']  = 'T%';

```
    $param = array(
     'type_element' => 'personne_morale',
     'order' => 'denomination',
     'limit' => 2,
     'filtres' => $filters
     );
```

This is my ios code which is not working it give error :

NSError *error;

```
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: @"https://www.eden-pme.com/edensoft/edenfiles/edensoft2014/api.php"];
        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];




        NSURLResponse *response;

        NSString *postString;
        postString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"api_public_key:api_private_key,6c8a4cf9044e48e4383b9f6a8f400055:94a337a9dd6fb58f5004f244187d5d39"];


        [request setURL:url];
        [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
        [request setValue:postString forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
       // NSURLResponse *response;
        NSData *res = [NSURLConnection  sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];

        NSArray *jsonArr = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:res options:kNilOptions error:&error];
            NSLog(@"%@",jsonArr);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NSString *urlAsStr=@"https://www.eden-pme.com/edensoft/edenfiles/edensoft2014/api.php";

```
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
[dict setObject:@"6c8a4cf9044e48e4383b9f6a8f400055" forKey:@"PHP_AUTH_USER"];
[dict setObject:@"94a337a9dd6fb58f5004f244187d5d39" forKey:@"PHP_AUTH_PW"];
[dict setObject:@"getAll" forKey:@"methode"];
[dict setObject:@"denomination" forKey:@"order"];
//[dict setObject:@"2" forKey:@"limit"];
[dict setObject:@"personne_morale" forKey:@"type_element"];
[dict setObject:@"1" forKey:@"return_array"];

NSString *stringJson = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:[NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dict options:0 error:nil] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] autorelease];

NSString *postString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"param=%@",stringJson];
NSData *postData = [postString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];


NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlAsStr]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request addValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

[request setHTTPBody:postData];


NSURLResponse *response;
NSError *err;
NSData *urlData=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&err];
```

dataArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:urlData options:kNilOptions error:&err];

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

change `[request setValue:postString forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];` to

```
[request setHTTPBody:[postString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```